# Get the parent folder for an ESXi virtual port group

Tags: powershell, powercli, esxi

I'm working on a script to organize VMs, datastores and networks for a multi-customer hosted ESX environment. One of the things I need to do is to get the current location of different objects to see if they need to be moved.

For datastores, I can do the following:

`$currentFolder = (Get-Datastore $datastore).ParentFolder.Name`

For networks, it doesn't work the same:

`$currentFolder = (Get-VirtualPortGroup -VMHost $esxhost -Name $network).ParentFolder.Name`

This doesn't return any results because there is no "ParentFolder" property on the VirtualPortGroup object.

**My question is**: Is there another way to get the parent folder name for a VirtualPortGroup?

**ANSWER:** The following code worked as a one-liner:

`Get-Folder -Id (Get-View -ViewType Network -Filter @{'Name' = $network}).Parent`

I had to create a criteria to filter multiple network names because the networks also live on a vDS as well. I did this by piping the Get-View command to:

`Where {$_.Name -like "*$criteria*"}`

I also needed to compare the folder names to see if they match where I want them to go, so I wrapped the line in parens () and added ".Name" to the end, like this:

`(Get-Folder -Id (Get-View -ViewType Network -Filter @{'Name' = $network} | Where {$_.Name -like "*$criteria*"}).Parent).Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about..

```
$NetworkView = Get-View -ViewType Network -Filter @{'Name' = 'TestVLAN' }
$PortGroupFolder = Get-Folder -Id $NetworkView.Parent
```

?

I suspect it's related to the VirtualPortGroup existing several times - once on each ESXi host / each VirtualSwitch - but the 'network' only shows up once on the vCenter and that's what gets put into the folder. This may be different if you have Distributed Switches, I guess.

Comment: I tried something like this based on a function by LucD. The results don't include the name, only Type and Value.

Comment: How much "like this"? Because this returns the folder name when I run it...

Comment: I tried your command exactly and it only gives Type and Value. It's something to do with how the Get-View returns the VirtualPortGroup Object. It's different than getting it directly.

Comment: OK, what's different? vSphere 6 and PowerCLI 6.3, I'm in the Inventory Networking section -> http://i.imgur.com/b2QdNQI.png a TestFolder with a network in it; I run these commands and the .Parent property has a Type and Value and then the Get-Folder turns it into the folder name: http://i.imgur.com/r0B0KIO.png

Comment: Ah. My problem was that I didn't see the 'Parent' property, but modifying the second line to use Get-Folder, I was able to get it to work. Sorry about the confusion!